# Best way to stop running pthreads using conditional variable

Tags: c, pthreads

Im working with pthreads in my c code. I create and start a thread (THREAD_1) in my main routine, where from THREAD_1, I call a routine to create again two new threads (THREAD_2, THREAD_3). All the three thread will be running parallel with milliseconds sleep in a conditional loop. After a certain condition is met I want to stop/exit the two threads (THREAD_2, THREAD_3) and then THREAD_1.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are all the threads executing the same condition? If yes, if the condition is met in any of the threads then you want to exit from all the threads?

Comment: @Jay: Actually I want to end first (THREAD_2 and THREAD_3) and then finally THREAD_1. After that I want to restart my main routine where again I want to start THREAD_1 and thereby THREAD2 and THREAD_3

Answer (score 0):

```
            while(true){
                    apr_thread_mutex_lock(mySharedObject->getMutex());
                    while (mySharedObject->getMessagesReady() == 0 && !mySharedObject->getEndThread()) {
                            apr_thread_cond_wait(mySharedObject->getCond(), mySharedObject->getMutex());
                    }
                    if (mySharedObject->getEndThread()){
                            apr_thread_mutex_unlock(mySharedObject->getMutex());
                            break;
                    }

                    apr_thread_mutex_unlock(mySharedObject->getMutex());

                    if (mySharedObject->getMessagesReady()>0){
                             myActiveProducer->send();
                    }

            }
```

This is the way that I've implemented it. Something wrong??